# Hide div by clicking another div jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div which when clicked, height changes so that the rest of the content becomes visible.
But I have a button inside this div which I would like to use as a "close-button", to change the height back to it's original value so the content is hidden again, but it's not working.
Here is the code:

```js
$('.scrollClick').click(function() {
  $(this).css("height", "350px");
});
$('.acceptCta').click(function() {
  $('.scrollClick').css("height", "27px");
});
```

```css
.scrollClick{
  font-family:inherit;
  background-color: #000E52;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 240px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  height: 27px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropContentBox{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  text-align: center;
}

.acceptCta{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #7CBD2B;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index:10;
}
.acceptCta:hover{
  background-color: #88D41B;
}
.acceptCta:hover .arrow{
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid #333;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.bouncer {
  position: relative;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: border-color 0.5s ease;
  animation: bouncer 2s infinite;

}

@keyframes bouncer {
  0% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }

  20% {
    bottom: 7px;
  }

  40% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }

  60% {
    bottom: 7px;
  }

  80% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollClick">
  Viktig informasjon! Les her&ensp;<i class="bouncer"></i>
  <div class="dropContentBox"><img src="/content/cnm/137449/600x600-banner-include-info-dishwasher-2019-no.png?$banner$">
    <div class="acceptCta">Jeg har lest og forstått&ensp;<i class="arrow"></i></div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So as you see in my jQuery code, I want the `.scrollClick` class to go back to it' original height, when clicking the `.acceptCta` div.
What am I doing wrong? Ty

Comment: Your .scrollClick DIV wraps around .acceptCta.  So you're actually triggering $('.acceptCta').click then $('.scrollClick').click every time you click the .acceptCta button.

Comment: As I suspected, thanks! @MaZoli solved it for me, it works perfectly as intended now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the click on your second button also triggers a click on your first button as the second button is *within* the first button. you can restructure your html or can stop propagation.

```
$('.scrollClick').click(function() {
  $(this).css("height", "350px");
});
$('.acceptCta').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.scrollClick').css("height", "27px");
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was suspecting, but I didn't know how to solve it. Thanks a bunch! It did the trick :D

Comment: You are welcome. Best practice would be a slightly restructured html structure though. Make a div around the "informasjon" and us it as a button. You can than use $(this).parent().toggleClass('active'); and set the height in the CSS.

Comment: Then I'd have to move that class outside .scrollClick div, or? Because there's an image and a button which appears when clicking the first click. You mean to have all the content as a button?
Won't be any problems using it as it is in your solution tho, right? Cuz I wouldn't know how to go through with your second suggestion :D This div is only visible on mobile tho, if that makes any difference. There's this image which is pushed far down on mobile screens which contains important information I'd like everyone to be informed of, that's why I made a cta which has to be pressed to dismiss it.

Comment: I made a fiddle so its probably easier to understand.
https://jsfiddle.net/nvxykgu9/1/

Comment: Oh now I get it, thanks a bunch! Btw is it possible to make it so that only the acceptCta button closes the div again? As of now it's possible to re-click on the same place to toggle it. I'd like the users to only be able to close it by pressing the button which says "I've read and understood(Jeg har lest og forstått)". Also, I moved the acceptCta out of the div, so that I can't close it by pressing the image, that's okay right?

Comment: Christ... you're a beast. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries. You are welcome ... if you keep learning you will master jQuery and Javascript quite soon as well!

Comment: Yeah I've been challenging myself at work, I wanna be able to develop things like this with ease! I keep taking tasks at work which requires JS and try to solve them, even tho it's not within my job description :D But today I've learned the concept of what you've helped me with and I'm sure I'll be able to use it in the future :D 
BTW, in your last fiddle I changed the last click function to apply for this class instead: ```.acceptCta```, now it excludes the img from the function. Also moved the CTA out of .dropToggler. https://jsfiddle.net/w6d8ko1t/ (If anyone needs this in the future).